# Ubuntu and windows bootable usb partition type

Tags: usb

So i want to create 2 bootable usb sticks: one for windows 7 and one for ubuntu 14.04. I want to boot those usb's in UEFI mode, both having 64bit ISO's, and install the two OS's in UEFI mode dual boot. (different story-different question). I have found that i must use a FAT32 or a FAT16 format for the usb.

So i go to disk utility (using master boot record) => edit partition. But there's so many partition type options.

My questions are:

1. Do i use FAT16 or FAT32?
2. If we take FAT16 for example, what option should i choose between the following:

   - FAT16 <32M (0x04)
   - Hidden FAT16 <32M (0x14)
   - FAT16 (0x06)
   - Hidden FAT16 (0x16)
   - w95 FAT16 (LBA) (0x0e)
   - Hidden w95 FAT16 (LBA) (0x1e)
   - EFI (FAT -12/16/32)

Thanks a lot for the upcoming support!

Comment: I'm kinda amazed to see FAT16 even mentioned. FAT32 is what Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator uses, if that helps.

Comment: I think the UEFI installer does allow FAT16, but have only seen FAT32 used. But you do not have to format in advance, at least with Ubuntu as the installer erases flash drive and fully installs it. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu OR: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: thanks, muru!

oldfred, i use ubuntu pangolin. You may be right about startup disk creator for making the ubuntu usb. But for the windows usb i must use 'winusb'. So i still need to know the answer to the 2nd question. Thanks!

Comment: We're sorry but AskUbuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

FAT32 has always worked good for me in a Live or Persistent install.
If you want persistent partitions, (casper-rw and home-rw), to get more persistence than FAT32 allows you, (4GB per file), you can make these ext2, (non-journaling)  or ext4, (journaling).

FAT32 offers improved disk utilisation over FAT16